# "There was no argument with the name `PriceBay` found on the field `countEarnings`.", graphql Hot Chocolate 12

Tags: graphql

Simple code:

```
public double RemoveTaxVat(double price, double taxVat)
        {
      taxVat = taxVat / 100;
      taxVat = taxVat + 1;
      price = price / taxVat;
          return price;
    }
        public double CountEarnings(double PriceBay, double PriceSell, double taxValue)
        {
           double earnings = RemoveTaxVat(PriceSell, taxValue) - PriceBuy;
           return earnings;
        }
```

Trying to calculate profit without VAT

```
query{
  countEarnings(priceBay: 3540, priceSell: 5050, taxValue: 23)
}

{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "There was no argument with the name `PriceBay` found on the field `countEarnings`.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "countEarnings"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "fieldName": "countEarnings",
        "argumentName": "PriceBay"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a case-sensitivity issue. Your resolver has:

```
CountEarnings(double PriceBay, double PriceSell, double taxValue)
```

But you're querying it with

```
countEarnings(priceBay: 3540, priceSell: 5050, taxValue: 23)
```

Should this be?

```
CountEarnings(PriceBay: 3540, PriceSell: 5050, taxValue: 23)
```

You don't show the GraphQL definition of the `CountEarnings` query so it's a bit hard to tell what the case of the arguments is meant to be. (Also your resolver has `CountEarnings` with an uppercase 'C' but you're querying it with lower case 'c' - only the schema knows for sure what your intent is.

Answer (score 0):

Letters are case insensitive as there is autocomplete in banana cake pop

type Query {
addVatTax(price: Float!, taxVat: Float!): Float!
removeTaxVat(price: Float!, taxVat: Float!): Float!
countEarnings(priceBuy: Float!, priceSell: Float!, taxValue: Float!): Float!
}